# Python x Zebra - How to print a label

Tags: python-3.x, printing, zebra-printers

I need to print labels from a Zebra printer using python. I have some zpl-code, which I'd like to somehow send to the printer.

I have searched the entire day, but was not capable of finding a working solution. Please help me, I am utterly lost.

Comment: How is your printer connected?

Comment: @DelphiCoder It is connected via Wi-Fi. I found a solution though, I am now using win32print to pass the raw zpl-code, and it works just the way it should! :)